# axios stop posting the request in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a website that interact with mysql server. Here is my server code
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrsMM.png)
Here is my client code
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss8t0.png)
and my problem is that after I have some error about mysql query like I insert a duplicate entry, I change the data of the form and submit again, the website remain no response. Can anyone have the same question and know what is the problem in my code.

I check the status of the network and i find that i cannot update the list after the insert is pending. How can I deal with the problem. Should i cancel the request?[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QTGa.png)

Comment: put some console.log(response) before setting both states and check what comes from your server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.